# Data Archiving from RDS to s3 but still access from application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

What is the right way to archive historical data from an Amazon RDS database but still be able to access it via application if some one wants it?

**Example:** I am trying to archive the data from the large tables in RDS to S3 to improve the performance.

So here is what I am trying to achieve:

- Archive the data having `creationTimestamp < 1 year ago` using `pt-archiver` (percona)
- Move archive data to s3 using SELECT
- Access the data using `s3 select` from application

To access the data based on timestamp (`creationDate`) I want to access either from RDS if less than an year OR from s3 if greater.

I am thinking to have this logic in application, But seems like there would be some challenges like how to handle range queries on timestamp, find all etc.

Let me know in case I am going wrong way.

Thanks in advance.